# colorsequence for more than 8 colors gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I normally used `set colorsequence podo` in gnuplot 5 to choose colors that are friendly to color blind individual.However my plot consist of `12` different keys and thus the line colors will repeat.How do i extend the colorspace to 12 colors from the default 8 while still taking care of color blindness and not having to specify the colors manually as far as possible.

Answer (score 6):

Extending the colorspace can be done with a initialization file. From `help set linetype`:

> The recommended way to do this is to add  to the run-time
>   initialization file ~/.gnuplot a sequence of commands like
>
> ```
>    if ((GPVAL_VERSION < 4.5) \
>    ||  (!strstrt(GPVAL_COMPILE_OPTIONS,"+USER_LINETYPES"))) \
>        exit
>    set linetype 1 lc rgb "dark-violet" lw 2 pt 0
>    set linetype 2 lc rgb "sea-green"   lw 2 pt 7
>    set linetype 3 lc rgb "cyan"        lw 2 pt 6 pi -1
>    set linetype 4 lc rgb "dark-red"    lw 2 pt 5 pi -1
>    set linetype 5 lc rgb "blue"        lw 2 pt 8
>    set linetype 6 lc rgb "dark-orange" lw 2 pt 3
>    set linetype 7 lc rgb "black"       lw 2 pt 11
>    set linetype 8 lc rgb "goldenrod"   lw 2
>    set linetype cycle 8
> ```
>
> Every time you run gnuplot the line types will be initialized to
>   these values. You may initialize as many linetypes as you like.

For colors which are friendly to colorblind people, `help colorsequence` refers to an article from Wong (2011) [Nature Methods 8:441]. I don't have access to the article, but it seems that they have some images from this article [online](http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v8/n6/fig_tab/nmeth.1618_F2.html). And it seems that this article recommends only 8 colors.

Have you already thought about using dotted or dashed lines?

Comment: While looking for Wong's article, I found http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/colorblind/, where one can find a 12-color palette (suited for colorblind people), but one would need to extract the respective colors from the image and define the colorsequence manually.

Comment: @Christoph do you mind extracting the colors and posting it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

with dotted lines:

```
# color cycle 1, dt 1 = solid line
set linetype  1 lc rgb "dark-violet" lw 1 dt 1 pt 0
set linetype  2 lc rgb "sea-green"   lw 1 dt 1 pt 7
set linetype  3 lc rgb "cyan"        lw 1 dt 1 pt 6 pi -1
set linetype  4 lc rgb "dark-red"    lw 1 dt 1 pt 5 pi -1
set linetype  5 lc rgb "blue"        lw 1 dt 1 pt 8
set linetype  6 lc rgb "dark-orange" lw 1 dt 1 pt 3
set linetype  7 lc rgb "black"       lw 1 dt 1 pt 11
set linetype  8 lc rgb "goldenrod"   lw 1 dt 1
# color cycle 2, dt 3 = dot line
set linetype  9 lc rgb "dark-violet" lw 1 dt 3 pt 0
set linetype 10 lc rgb "sea-green"   lw 1 dt 3 pt 7
set linetype 11 lc rgb "cyan"        lw 1 dt 3 pt 6 pi -1
set linetype 12 lc rgb "dark-red"    lw 1 dt 3 pt 5 pi -1
set linetype 13 lc rgb "blue"        lw 1 dt 3 pt 8
set linetype 14 lc rgb "dark-orange" lw 1 dt 3 pt 3
set linetype 15 lc rgb "black"       lw 1 dt 3 pt 11
set linetype 16 lc rgb "goldenrod"   lw 1 dt 3
#
set linetype cycle 16
```

problem is, the `png` terminal will keep showing solid lines, so we need the `pngcairo` terminal:

```
set term pngcairo dashed size 800,600 font "sans" linewidth 3
```

to show smaller dots, use `dt "."`